# Accessing JSON object properties directly and log it

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I'm trying to access JSON Object properties directly and log it, here is my function :

```
loadProcesses(filter?){

this._postService.getAllProcess(filter)
.subscribe(
    res=> {
        this.processListe = res;
       // console.log(this.processListe.)
    }
,null,
() =>{
    console.log("get processes liste" + filter)

});
```

So this.processListe contain a JSON Object, and my JSON format is like this:

```
{"Person": {
   "id": "A256",
   "name": "GET",
   "status": "active",
   "description": "hardworking, openminded",
   ...
```

So it will contains exactly the same things, for example if i want to simply print the label on a console log how can i do it ??

Comment: I added a better solution in the responses below :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```js
function parseObject(obj)
{
   for(var key in obj)
   {
      console.log("key: " + key + ", value: " + obj[key])
      if(obj[key] instanceof Object)
      {
        parseObject(obj[key]);
      }
   }
}
```

just call parseObject(res) in the subscribe method.

Comment: thank you man, it did show up only the first Propretie it's an object that contains under it it own propertie,, how can i access the sub properties in thos case please ??

Comment: Edited my answer to support nested json

Comment: thank you a lot, i'll reform it to my needs thank you again

Answer (score 9):

parse it and access the fields.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(filter);
obj.Person.id; 
//etc
```

Comment: i did change my function as you mentioned, and i'm having this error : angular2.dev.js:1206 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1, this is what i did : 

subscribe(
            res=> {
                this.processListe = res;
                this.obj = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log("++++ value is :++++++++" + this.obj.id);
            }

Answer (score 0):

parse it in the .subscribe:

```
res => this.processListe = res.json();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, 

i'm having this error :  angular2.dev.js:1206 Uncaught TypeError: res.json is not a function


and this is my new function : 

 .subscribe(
            res=> {
                this.processListe = res.json();
                console.log("++++ value is :++++++++" + this.processListe.id);
            }

Answer (score 0):

a better solution is to declare your response with any :

```
loadProcesses(filter?){

this._postService.getAllProcess(filter)
.subscribe(
    (res: any)=> {
        this.processListe = res;
       // console.log(this.processListe.)
    }
,null,
() =>{
    console.log("get processes liste" + filter)

});
```

this way you can access any attirbute in your response